# gnome-do style keyboard shortcuts in Unity

Tags: 10.10, unity, ubuntu-netbook, shortcut-keys

Will the Unity launcher in 10.10 UNE have gnome-do style keyboard shortcuts?

i.e. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> for quick search and application launch

If not, can it be customized to allow this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: As of Ubuntu 11.04, this answer is wrong.  See [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/unity-keyboard-mouse-shortcuts) for a large number of keyboard shortcuts, including an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> launcher.

As far as I'm aware this is currently not possible.

One of the requirements for switching to Unity on the desktop is that it needs accessibility work.  A part of this work will be to ensure that Unity can be driven by the keyboard, so I would expect that this *will* be possible in the Ubuntu 11.04 release.

What *I* use for Do-style keyboard shortcuts in Unity is Do; it's a great complement to the Unity shell.  The main problem is that Unity eats `win` keypresses, so the default Do shortcut is not available.  It's easy to change the Do keybinding to something else, though.

Comment: Yes, came to same conclusion it wasn't possible.  Thankfully, 11.04 does now have this feature.

Answer (score 2):

`System`>`Preferences`>`Keyboard Shorcuts`>`Show the panel's "Run Application" dialog box`

This launches `gnome-keybinding-properties`.  From there you should be able to change the default, `alt`+`f2` to `alt`+`space`.

Comment: Thanks, but I believe the "Run Application" dialog is disabled with Unity (10.10 Netbook edition) - least alt + f2 seems to do nothing

Comment: Is your background set to a solid color? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/398826

Answer (score 1):

`Alt + F2` is not working 'cos is a function of gnome-panel, Unity uses is proper panel. `Super` enable numerical shortcuts to sidebar elements. That's all for now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not out of the box. After upgrading to Ubuntu Netbook 10.10, install gnome-do and then modify its default shortcut key.  The windows key is hijacked by Unity, so the default gnome-do run shortcut Win-Space won't work. Change it to something else like Alt-Space and you'll be good to go with a slick run dialog!

Answer (score 1):

You can, for now, bind the keyboard shortcut Alt+F2 to the command "unity --show" to bridge the period of no keyboard shortcuts being available. Far from ideal, but workable in the meantime.