# Is there a shortcut in Unity to hide/unhide the Launcher?

Tags: unity

I think it would be convenient to be able to hide/unhide the Launcher from a keyboard shortcut. then I am not forced to use the mouse to do so. I could hide the Launcher and maximize a window all from the keyboard.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the 'Windows' button on your keyboard to bring up the Unity Launcher.

If you keep the Windows button held down and look on the icons on your Launcher, you will see the keyboard shortcuts for launching these apps. (i.e. Win+1, Win+2, etc, Win+s, Win+f, Win+a).

Here are all the keyboard shortcuts:

- [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/unity-keyboard-mouse-shortcuts)

Comment: As you can see from the link, you can also enter Alt-F1 and the launcher will unhide. You can then use cursor keys to select the application you want. Helpful if you want to launch something more than 10 places down in the Launcher.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think the "so-called" solution would be to go into Applications / Keyboard / Shortcuts / Windows. There is TWO option called "toggle fullscreen mode" and "toggle maximizing state"

- Especially for "toggle fullscreen mode", the applications remain THE SAME with all the toolbars & such and the screen will hide your top panel and the launcher also

I use that as a "so-called" & "low tech" solution

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multitouch cabable touchpad?

If so. There are two default actions to hide / show the launcher in Ubuntu.

four finger swipe to the right (show launcher)
four finger swipe to the left (hide launcher)