# Unity Launcher Hotkeys doesn't launch a new instance of my application

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I'm not quite sure, if i can pinpoint what caused this, but now the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc.. hotkeys to launch applications on the launcher don't respond at all.

Nor do Super+a and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, but <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> for Expo does. Any ideas as how to troubleshoot this? (When I hold them down and type them, the letters just fall through to the application in focus).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! 11.04 is currently in Beta so things might not work right. Please file a bug on this issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 2):

Super+1, Super+2… just have a similar effect than clicking on the icon with the mouse.
This mean that it will focus the current application if aready started, or launch application not started.

You can force starting a new instance of the application with Super + Shift +

See [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/unity-keyboard-mouse-shortcuts)