# How to show only opened apps in the current workspace on unity?

Tags: unity, workspaces

I've never been a "workspace user" but now I'm starting to feel the need to separate my work..

Is it possible, on unity, to only show apps on the running on the current workspace?

An example of what I'm looking for would be:

1. Firefox is running on workspace 1.
2. I'm on the 2nd and click on Firefox.
3. I get a new window instead of being sent back to the first workspace.

I think this something similar was possible on classic gnome and maybe it works for unity too, however I don't remember how.

Comment: Good question, I always wanted to see that as well. Have only those apps displayed in the launcher that actually are on my current workspace.

Comment: aargh!! same on my side (upgraded to 11.10). now working with workspaces is a big pain. I wonder why it didn't appear on 11.04...

Comment: Better yet, each workspace (they were called workspaces long before) should have it's own profile. For example, it can have it's own icons locked to the launcher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 13.04

Raring has had a number of improvements in this area which should improve the workflow for someone using multiple workspaces.

Lets look at some examples:

In this example you can see that I have Firefox and Terminal open in different workspaces - with firefox open in two instances on separate workspaces:

[image: pic1]

Look closely at the Launcher:

[image: pic2]

Firefox is shown with a full *pip* - thats the arrow shown.  It only shows one since this is the only one running in this workspace.

The terminal *pip* is a narrow version indicating that its running in a different workspace.  Thus you get an instant indication of BOTH applications running in the workspace as well as possible other applications running.

If you had two instances of firefox running in the workspace you would have two *pips*.

[image: pic4]

To create another instance of Firefox on another workspace, right-click and choose one of the first two options shown:

[image: pic3]

To flip between different instances, choose from the window title shown in the right-click quicklist.

Comment: I think the highlight box on the last image is in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 8):

As far as opening another instance of a running program in a new workspace goes, you can just middle-click on the icon instead of left-clicking - but I don't think there's any way to hide applications running on another workspace at the moment.  Maybe this is a feature you could request by filing a wishlist bug?

Answer (score 7):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> to scale affect all apps open on current workspace

Press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to scale affect all apps open on all workspaces.

- [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/unity-keyboard-mouse-shortcuts)

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but thanks anyway. I simply dont want to see and be affected (firefox example) by other workspace apps on the unity bar

Answer (score 5):

There are open bugs according to this post:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1724571

The bugs are:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/689733
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/683170