# Prevent unity launcher icons from highlighting across workspaces

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, workspaces

I have Ubuntu 15.04 with Unity DE and enabled the multiple workspaces.

Now currently, when I open e.g. Firefox in workspace 1, move to workspace 2 and open a Terminal there, I still have the Firefox icon highlighted on workspace 2, just with a non-filled white arrow on the left instead of a filled white arrow if it was on the currently active workspace.
See the screenshot:

[image: launcher, multiple workspaces]

What I would prefer is a behaviour like the one you may set up using XFCE and their multiple workspaces, i.e. that you can tell Unity to *only highlight running programs on the current workspace*. That would mean that in my example, if I'm on workspace 2, the Firefox icon has to be normal and not highlighted, just as if the program was not running at all.

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour? How do I configure it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show only opened apps in the current workspace on unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34400/how-to-show-only-opened-apps-in-the-current-workspace-on-unity)

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Sorry, but I already saw that linked question. It's similar, but not the same. Especially does none of the answers fit my question. I want that each workspace is visually independent from each other, so that from one workspace, you can't see which applications are running on others.