# Ubuntu 18.04 - dock behavior for apps in multiple workspaces

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, ubuntu-dock

The Unity Launcher in Ubuntu 16.04 had a smart way of representing applications in different workspaces:

- the pip next to the application would be solid for applications in the current workspace, a narrow version would appear for applications in a different workspace
- when an application (e.g., pdf reader) is opened multiple times over multiple workspaces, the dock would only indicate the number of opened versions in the current workspace

Here this behavior is discussed for Ubuntu 13.04: [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/279034/521206).

It seems that this behavior is missing in Ubuntu 18.04, and so far I could not find any extensions or tweaks to retrieve it. Any ideas?

Note: I am aware of modifications of the dock so that it only shows applications of the current workspace (as proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992558/how-can-i-configure-the-ubuntu-dock-to-show-windows-only-from-the-current-worksp) for instance), but I am really looking for the more advanced behavior as exemplified above.