# Unity 2D documentation?

Tags: unity-2d, documentation

Is there any documentation for Unity 2D? The only settings available seem to be buried in gconf and are a bit cryptic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mariano Chavero has made "A simple GUI for Unity-2D Settings": http://marianochavero.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/a-simple-gui-for-unity-2d-settings-ubuntu-11-04/ This may not answer your question but might help decrypting the options in gconf-editor.

Comment: Looks good, i'll take a nice intuitive GUI over a document decrypting gconf settings any day. Call me lazy ;)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Wiki page for Unity2D](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity2D) it's architecture is very close to Unity and shares all the same backend components so the documentation for Unity would be relative.

The Unity2D version's only difference is it uses Qt/QML for the UI portion while utilizing the existing Unity core components for indicators, places etc.

Having said all that there is currently no documentation for Unity and is filed as a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/600875).

There is a useful list of keyboard and mouse shortcuts here [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/unity-keyboard-mouse-shortcuts)

Comment: Sure, but as far as user-facing configuration, the normal Unity option (compizconfig-settings-manager) is no good, and there doesn't seem to be anything about the gconf settings. I mean, what the hell does "use strut" mean?

Comment: Not too sure about 'use strut' myself....did a little more digging around and came up with this site: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/packages/show/267972. I haven't had a good look through it yet but note the change log for version 11.04.1

Comment: @Seret - also found this article that goes into good detail on use and settings for Unity: http://theravingrick.blogspot.com/2011/04/my-effort-at-writing-help-for-unity.html