# How to move windows around and between screens?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, window

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity keyboard/mouse shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/unity-keyboard-mouse-shortcuts)

On MS Windows we can use <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd> to move a window to the right and the left of the screen, maximize, minimize and even move it to another screen. Is there a way to configure this feature on Unity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Unity, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> to move the window to the bottom left of the screen.

You can also use Numpad 4 to move it left, Numpad 7 to move it top left, Numpad 8 to move it top, Numpad 2 to move it bottom, Numpad 9 to move it top right, Numpad 6 to move it right and Numpad 3 to move it bottom right.

I hope this helped you,

Daniel