# How to move windows around and between monitors, using keyboard short cuts?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, window

On MS Windows we can use <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd> to move a window to the right and the left of the screen, maximize, minimize and even move it to another screen. Is there a way to configure this feature on Gnome?

Comment: I have kde and super + arrows moves to next monitor edge and to another screen.

Comment: I recommend you change the "correct answer" selection to Simon D's as it is most up to date and helpful these days.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>NUMPAD 4</kbd> (left edge)
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>NUMPAD 6</kbd> (right edge)

Make sure you are using the NUMPAD cursor keys, not the dedicated ones, if you have those. Otherwise, it'll switch workspaces.

Note that these shortcuts only work on non-maximized windows. Un-maximizing any selected window can be done using

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>NUMPAD 5</kbd> (center)

List of Unity keyboard shortcuts here in case you haven't seen them.

[What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/unity-keyboard-mouse-shortcuts)

Comment: It doesn't work on Gnome

Comment: @Jader Dias In *what way* does *what* "not work" on Gnome?

Comment: @ændrük In my understanding Unity keyboard shortcuts don't work on Gnome

Comment: @JaderDias: But they do (at least these particular keys, in 12.10), and this is great! See http://askubuntu.com/a/222902/30266 for more detail.

Comment: These are great, I only recently discovered them. The one thing they don't do (which the OP asked for) is moving windows from one monitor to another.

Comment: Whether maximized or not, it just seems to "snap" the window to half of the current monitor instead of moving to a different monitor. (Using 16.04)

Answer (score 35):

In Ubuntu 17.10, the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd> keyboard shortcuts move the window between the different monitors.

Can be modified under Settings > Devices > Keyboard > Navigation > Move window one monitor up/down/to the left/to the right.

Comment: The same in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. This is the up-to-date answer, the others are more or less outdated.

Comment: This works in Ubuntu 21.10

Answer (score 26):

The [Put Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/) extension implements this feature. After installing it, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> move the active window to the previous/next screen, respectively -- just as in Windows. This works even in a three-monitor setup, and also [moving maximized windows](https://github.com/negesti/gnome-shell-extensions-negesti/issues/37) now works reliably.

Frychiko's [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/36929/30266) works great in a two-monitor setting but suffers issues when moving maximized windows.

Tested with Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: After installing, you need to use the gnome-shell-extension-prefs tool to configure the keys used (they don't show up in Keyboard settings). I didn't have that tool (I installed `gnome-shell` in Ubuntu), but `apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions` let me run "Tweak Tool".

Comment: If you've set the monitors to be above each other then you need to use `Super + Shift + Up/Down` This also works on Fedora 28 (Gnome 3)

Comment: works on Fedora too

Answer (score 16):

ALT+F7 which select window and move using arrow. Press Enter to release the window.

Comment: Is a valid answer, but it doesn't achieve the desired behavior

Comment: Additionally press SHIFT to move faster, or CTRL to move slower when using the arrow keys

Comment: For me, using 16.04, none of the other answers works for moving between monitors except this one (without installing an extension, which seems unnecessary).

Comment: Same here - this is a working solution for moving a window out of a dysfunctional monitor, caused by https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14743.

Comment: that's so weird having to press a keyboard shortcut for such common task

Comment: This is great when one of your displays or screens is wonky, your mouse is temporarily broken, and you're trying to move a window from an obscured or invisible place (e.g. covered by "Oh no! Something has gone wrong" blanked page") to a functional display/screen.

Comment: This answer still works! Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 (Pop!_OS) with Gnome 3.28.2:

- Moving window in current display:
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Arrows</kbd>
- Moving window to other display:
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Arrows</kbd>

*Edit:*

The initial answer works (at least) for Pop!_OS 18.04 - the keyboard shourtcuts might be custom.

Later found this [Gnome wiki page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/KeyboardShortcuts) which states that it should be
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Arrows Left/Right</kbd>

Comment: does not work for ubuntu 19.04

Comment: I might have distro-specific keyboard shortcuts.

https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/KeyboardShortcuts states that it should be
Shift + Super + Left/Right

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Frychiko 's answer:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>num_pad_5</kbd> maximizes and minimize window
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>num_pad_8</kbd> or <kbd>num_pad_2</kbd>  moves windows to the top and bottom edge respectively.

it's really easy to achieve this on laptops too - just add an <kbd>fn</kbd> key to your combination and you're done!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as it only moves them within the current monitor and will not move them to a different monitor.

Comment: The original question was edited.

Answer (score -1):

By using Ctrl + Shift + Alt + Arrow combination, you can move any windows to the other screens.

Comment: In my installation it would move only windows between workspaces. When I say screens you should think in a multi-monitor setup.

Comment: You should make it clear in your question that you don't mean workspaces.

Comment: @Roddie He made that clear by using the word [screens](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man5/xorg.conf.5.html#contenttoc13) instead of [workspaces](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces.html).

Comment: No, he hasn't made it clear, hence why someone has offered this very answer.