# How to move a window between monitors with Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome, window-manager, window

I see this question is "answered" by stating that there is no way to do this in GNOME:
[How to move windows around and between monitors, using keyboard short cuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36616/how-to-move-windows-around-and-between-screens)
I have doubts that it should be impossible and I really want to do it.

Is there really no way to do this is Gnome? This is my output from xrandr that I don't know how to use:

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 3840 x 1200, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 3840 x 1200
default connected 3840x1200+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   3840x1200      50.0*
```

Comment: Do you mean between monitors. OR do you mean between X11 screens? Between monitors is possible using XRandR or xinarama. XRandR was working out of box for me.

Comment: I have kde and super + arrows moves to next edge as described in other question.

Comment: Just to confirm - do you mean with Gnome desktop or Unity?

Comment: not a duplicate of 28086, as this other is about unity, and other reasons (see other question)

Comment: I mean default ubuntu gnome with two physical displays. When I open a PDF document for instance it is sent to the television for no reason even though the TV is turned off.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following works for me (Ubuntu 12.10, Gnome Shell):

`Ctrl + Alt + NUMPAD 6` moves the active window to the screen on the right

`Ctrl + Alt + NUMPAD 4` moves the active window to the screen on the left

Note that, for some applications like Firefox and Thunderbird, this does not work for maximized windows for me -- the window seems to be moving, but only until I release the keys. This could be a bug in the corresponding applications or Gnome Shell. As a workaround, I unmaximize first using `Ctrl + Alt + NUMPAD 5`, and maximize back later with the same combination.

This is inspired by answers from [How to move windows around and between monitors, using keyboard short cuts?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36616/30266).

**EDIT**: For some obscure reason these shortcuts stopped working for me. `Super + NUMPAD 7` and `Super + NUMPAD 9` achieve a similar effect.

Comment: That's good but did not work right away. I'm patching with the latest ubuntu updates to see what changes I can make to enable the functionality.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz: This is strange. I have scanned the list of my installed extensions, but didn't find anything suspicious. How would I find out who is responsible for handling the above key combinations in my system? Which Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: I currently use the alt key and pull the window with the mouse. I use ubuntu `3.2.0-38-generic #61-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 19 12:18:21 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: @NickRosencrantz: Have you tried Ctrl+Alt+NUMPAD 5, Super + 7, Ctrl+Alt+NUMPAD 5?

Comment: None of the shortcuts are working :(

Comment: This is to confirmed that this still works as of Ubuntu 15.04 running gnome-shell on a dual monitor.

Comment: It doesn't work with three monitors though, the middle monitor is ignored.

Comment: On Fedora 24, I achieve this through Super + Shift + (arrow)

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio 's answer also [matches the most up voted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/350287/8989) on the duplicate question