# Move window to another screen without compiz

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors

I know how to move windows to another workspace, but I'm specifically looking for a keyboard shortcut to move a window to the other screen in a multi-monitor set, but **without using compiz**, since I'd rather not to install it. Is there such a shortcut? I'm on Gnome 3.16.

Thanks.

Comment: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-workspaces-movewindow.html.en

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move windows around and between monitors, using keyboard short cuts?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36616/how-to-move-windows-around-and-between-monitors-using-keyboard-short-cuts)

Comment: According to that answer, the unity keyboard shortcuts are supposed to work for gnome shell as well.

Comment: ref: http://askubuntu.com/questions/164208/how-to-move-a-window-between-monitors-with-gnome-shell

Comment: You basically want xdotool. With dual monitor set up, desktop is basically spread. For example screen 1 is from 0 to 1024 in width and screen 2 is starting on 1024 to 2048. I am on mobile so 8 cannot post complete answer right now, but look into xdotool , and its functions getactivewindow and windowmove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is it:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>NUMPAD 4</kbd> (to the monitor at left)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>NUMPAD 6</kbd> (to the monitor at right)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Gnome website](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-workspaces-movewindow.html.en):

> Select the window that you want to move (for example, using the <kbd>Super</kbd> +<kbd>Tab</kbd> window switcher).
>
> Press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> to move the window to a workspace which is above the current workspace on the workspace selector.
>
> Press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> to move the window to a workspace which is below the current workspace on the workspace selector.

Comment: Thanks but I know that, I wrote it in the beginning of my comment. I don't want to move the window to another workspace, but to another screen (or monitor)

Comment: @FrankS101 sorry, the compiz talk threw me off. You know compiz isn't even compatible with Gnome shell anyhow.

Comment: (I realize this doesn't answer the question but it answered my question.)