# Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome bar on all monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, 18.04, gnome-shell

I know many people have asked already how to get the Gnome shell top bar to display on all monitors in Ubuntu 18.04 but the answers were never satisfactory. The [multi-monitors addon](https://github.com/spin83/multi-monitors-add-on/tree/master/multi-monitors-add-on%40spin83) adds a bar that lacks the shutdown and other buttons (which is the main reason I want the bar on the other monitors as well).

Is there any other option to get the bar on all monitors? E.g. write my own extension and just copy the whole bar onto the other desktops?

Comment: I'm wondering whether trying the same approaches on the non-Ubuntu Gnome would work? I'm still on 17.10 but for me I've just been using the standard Gnome on X11 (instead of Ubuntu Gnome at login) and all the extensions seem to work better there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you [can't right now](https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/issues/372). There's [an open issue](https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/issues/35) which you can follow to get updates about when this will be implemented.

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot to accept your answer as the right one. Three years later :D

Comment: Although it seems it's possible now, according to the closed issue. I'm not really using gnome anymore, so I can't test it right now.