# Top bar for all monitors (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: gnome, 20.04, multiple-monitors, top-bar

It seems that many people have asked how to get the top bar on multi-monitors for Ubuntu 18.04 (e.g., [Ubuntu 18.04: Top bar for all monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030460/ubuntu-18-top-bar-for-all-monitors), [Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome bar on all monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034787/ubuntu-18-04-gnome-bar-on-all-monitors)). There is no satisfactory answer there. I'd like to know if a solution exists for Ubuntu 20.04?

EDIT: I've already tried the Mutli Monitors Add-On but it doesn't work properly for me. I'm not able to get sounds parameters on both top bars and there are problems with some indicators.

Comment: There isn't a version of Ubuntu called "Ubuntu 20", only "Ubuntu 20.04" and "Ubuntu 20.10". I've edited the post

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

https://github.com/realh/multi-monitors-add-on

Remove old versions of Multi Monitors add-on from `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

Download updated extension from https://github.com/realh/multi-monitors-add-on and put `multi-monitors-add-on@spin83` folder into `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> enter <kbd>r</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to reset Gnome Shell.

After that, you will be able to enable Multi Monitors add-on

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately I get this error `No JS module 'viewSelector' found in search path` in 22.04 with v19 zip-version. Any tip?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need since the past two days, and found little information on 20.04. However, starting with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029306/6100) and [that one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1030468/6100), I was able to get it working by doing the following:

1. Install GNOME Shell Extensions: `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions`
2. Install the GNOME Shell integration browser extension and the Multi Monitors Add-On:

   - I simply visited https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/
   - There was notice at the top, with a link to install the browser extension:

   > To control GNOME Shell extensions using this site you must install GNOME Shell integration that consists of two parts: browser extension and native host messaging application.
   > [Click here to install browser extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/#). See [wiki page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation) for native host connector installation instructions.

   - After installing the extension, a widget appears on that page which allows you to toggle the extension On or Off; toggling On brings a popup asking you if you want to enable the shell extension; after confirming it just worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already tried the Mutli Monitors Add-On but it doesn't work properly for me. I'm not able to get sounds parameters on both top bars and there are problems with some indicators.

Comment: Ah right; it might be worth mentioning those details in the title, or at the very least in the body of your question. For me, it didn't matter much that those indicators do not appear, I mainly wanted the time & date.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll add those information in the body. I mainly want the sound parameters when my primary monitor is in full screen mode (running a virtual machine for example).