# Ubuntu dash on second monitor

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, gnome-shell

Ubuntu's dash is only showing on my primary, big display. Can I somehow make it so I can access it from my second screen too?

Comment: Refer to this for the top bar: [Ubuntu 18: Top bar for all monitors](https://askubuntu.com/q/1030460/480481)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ubuntu 18.04

Go to *Settings* -> *Dock*

and select *All screens* inside *Display on* option (3rd lines)

you can see this option selected in my screenshot below (text are in French, sorry) :

[image]

Comment: That solved it. Is there a similar setting for the panel on the top?

Comment: @Future watch this link https://askubuntu.com/a/1030468/829702

Comment: that seemed to fix it. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

## Ubuntu 22.04

Go to *Settings* -> *Appearance* -> *Dock* -> click on *Show on* dropdown -> Select *All displays*

And as @damadam said, for the top bar use https://askubuntu.com/a/1030468/829702

See Screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnAEB.png