# How do I handle windows that are too tall?

Tags: gnome-shell, window

Sometimes, I open an application and it opens a window that is too tall for my display. It also doesn't let me resize the window to make it less tall, and it doesn't have a maximize button. In Ubuntu (GNOME Shell), I can drag and drop the title bar to move the window, but I can't move the window higher than the top edge of the screen, which would have been useful to see the lower part of the window.

How do I find a workaround for windows that are too tall to fit in the display? Is there a way to force resize the window? Is there a way to move the window higher than the top edge of the monitor?

(An example of this issue: in VirtualBox, click File -> Import Appliance... The resulting window is too tall on some screen resolutions.)

I am interested in answers in GNOME Shell, as well as other environments.

Comment: _(An example of the issue:_ What is after that? +1

Comment: Not an answer I suppose, but using the <super>+<Arrow keys> can manage windows in GNOME. Up arrow key is to maximize it, down arrow key is to "un-maximize" it or minimize it if it's not maximized. IIRC, the left and right arrow keys will "half-maximize" it respectively to the left or side of the screen. (not on my Ubuntu atm, so can't confirm)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### In Ubuntu (GNOME Shell):

There is another way to move windows in GNOME Shell. Drag and drop the window while holding down the <kbd>super</kbd> key (also known as the <kbd>windows</kbd> key). You can start the drag and drop operation from any part of the window, as long as the <kbd>super</kbd> key is held down. This will allow you to move the window, even past the top edge of the screen. Now you can see the bottom part of the window.

Comment: OK, I’ve got to seriously wonder: Why `Super`? Why not `Alt` like _almost every other desktop environment out there_ (including Windows)? I suspect this is yet another case of the developers thinking they know better than the entire rest of the world, but...

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Because alt-drag is used to bring up file copy/move options? Maybe?

Comment: @IronEagle But they can only use that particular combination for a different purpose _because_ they are using a different set of hotkeys to move windows, so I would argue that’s a symptom of the decision, not the reason for the decision.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn - then maybe it stems from choosing whether windows are part of the operating system or the underlying program?  `Alt` is generally used for within-window shortcuts, and `Super` is generally used for OS shortcuts, it seems.  Not saying that they made the right choice.

Comment: Not sure about Gnome-Shell, but in multiple window managers I've used through the years, you can also use Super/Alt+right-click-drag to resize the window from any part of it.

Answer (score 12):

#### In Lubuntu (LXQt):

In other desktop environments (than Gnome shell) for example LXQt of Lubuntu, you can press the left **<kbd>Alt</kbd>** key and use the left button of the mouse to drag the window.

Comment: You know what, I decided to edit my question to make it more broad so that this answer is also valid. Thanks, @sudodus.

Answer (score 2):

**Resize without Mouse**

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

You can choose either; `Move` or `Resize`,
and use arrow keys to fit it.