# How can I open another window of an application in Unity 2D e.g. another Terminal?

Tags: 11.04, unity-2d

I prefer a keyboard shortcut..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you middle-click on a launcher item, a new instance will be opened even if you already have another instance opened.

Comment: Middle click worked. Is there key combo? I see Super+Shift+[1..0] should do it in Unity but it doesn't seem to work in Unity 2D.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> will open you a Terminal ( as much as you want)

Also check this wallpaper out, for hotkeys in unity:
[What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/unity-keyboard-mouse-shortcuts/36648#36648)

Don't know if they work in Unity 2D also, but i think so.

Comment: The wallpaper is useful but it is not really an answer to my question as it is for Unity 3D. Also the tabs in a Terminal is irrelevant. 10x for the attempt though.

Comment: yea, i didn't know that they do not work in Unity 2D.