# Will Unity offer more keyboard configuration?

Tags: unity, keyboard, customization, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

I want my cake and to eat it too.  And in Linux I can usually do that.  (And it's free cake!)  I'm a little shocked that it hasn't been easier (or as far as I know, even possible) to change the keyboard shortcuts for Unity.  Someone suggested in another post that the Unity launcher can be changed from Super to Ctrl + Super, then I can map the other keybindings that I want.  But I like a lot of the features that Unity has with only pressing the Super key (I find it a lot easier to press Super+e than Ctrl+Super+e).  However, I want to be able to change what some of the bindings in Unity are, primarily change Super+t from opening trash to opening a terminal (currently Ctrl+Alt+t).

With that background, here is my question: is Unity working on allowing users to customize the keybindings to their preference?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

Many of keybindings you can change in Compiz Config Settings Manager (*ccsm* command).