# What is the shortcut to lock computer?

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity keyboard/mouse shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/unity-keyboard-mouse-shortcuts)

What is the shortcut to lock computer?

Comment: The question this is marked a duplicate of asks about the *Unity* shortcut (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`L`), whereas this question is tagged `gnome`, where the shortcut is in fact different (`Super`+`L`). So I would vote for removing the *duplicate* flag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

shortcut to lock computer is ctrl + alt + L

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl + Alt + L

Try this handy cheatsheet wallpaper: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf1y5.png

Comment: Brilliant that..especially all the bits to put stuff in each corner...verging on the fancy dancy!

Comment: Agree.. Super+W and Super+S used to be the other way round, so its pretty useful if you want to get used to the new shortcuts quickly.