# Resize window to half width

Tags: 11.10, kubuntu, window-manager

Is there an easy / convenient way to resize any window on Kubuntu to half width of the screen?

With todays wide screen monitors, I have enough space to fit two windows side by side, but I never do that because the Maximize-button is so easy to click and I guess I'm just too lazy to fiddle with the window width manually. Is there something as a button that resizes my window on the left half of the monitor and a button to resize to the right half of the monitor?
Now the catch is that I have a two monitor set up, which would imply I can potentially fit 2 windows on each of the two monitors.

[App that enables hotkeys to half-screen a window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47175/app-that-enables-hotkeys-to-half-screen-a-window) doesn't work on Kubuntu <s>11.04</s> 11.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, on Ubuntu, when dragged to the right/left of the screen fully, it will expand to one half, not sure if it's the same on KDE though.

Comment: Works like a charm, even with double monitor setup. I noticed this behaviour before for full screen maximizing when touching the top screen border. Never realized it would work this way too.

Answer (score 2):

Try **Ctrl + Super + Left** and **Ctrl + Super + Right** to put the active window at the left/right half of the screen. I changed the keyboard shortcut with compiz to **Ctrl + Alt + Keypad 4** and **Ctrl + Alt + Keypad 6** so I can also resize to the lower/upper half of the screen and to a quarter of the screen with the keypad.