# Is there a Command + ` equivalent (cycle through windows)?

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

On the Mac, I use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (the tilde) to cycle through windows in the current application (eg terminal or chrome). It's like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> except only for the current application's windows. Possibly for Compiz but without any flashy Exposé like graphics?

Answer (score 12):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> - <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> do this by default.

The desktop will map whatever key is above the tab key to do this, on US keyboards it's the ` key.

- [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

Comment: Can you do this with compiz? I can't find the appropriate setting.

Answer (score 2):

In Xfce you can use <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (super is the "Windows" key on Microsoft keyboards). Not sure if this works in other window managers.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 12.04, by default, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>above tab</kbd> does this.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ Window Number.

For example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+1 for first window. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+2 for second window etc...

In firefox and chrome you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>