# Unity hotkey for minimizing current window?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, gui

What are the hotkeys for switching the current window between maximized, normal, and minimized states? If some of these don't exist, can I set them somewhere?

Comment: ..for more shortcuts: [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In Ubuntu 12.04 Unity the shortcuts can be found in:

System Settings | Hardware | Keyboard | Shortcuts | Windows.

In a default installation the keys are the following:

- Maximize: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>
- Restore: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>
- Minimize: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (the keypad 0)

Comment: Minimize doesn't work for me either with the "0" key on the top of the keyboard. It does work with the "0" key from the keypad, however.

Comment: `It does work with the "0" key from the keypad, however.` Even when the Numlock is off. Quite wierd..

Comment: I opened CCSM and found that Minimize is associated per default to <Control><Alt>KP0. not very useful on a laptop... luckily CCSM is meant for customizing this and more.

Comment: still worksish for 13.04.  sub `restore` for `minimize`

Comment: Still applies to 14.04.

Comment: Still applies to 15.10.

Comment: `super + H` works on 18.04

Answer (score 15):

- To minimise <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>,<kbd>N</kbd>
- To maximise <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>

Depending on your internationalization settings the key to press after <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will be different (e.g. <kbd>U</kbd> to minimize with french settings).

Comment: This will minimize only current window. Is there anything to minimize all at once/

Comment: ^ Super+D is what you are looking for..

Answer (score 14):

try <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> in ubuntu to minimize the current window

Comment: Officially this is a "Hide" shortcut, there is no "minimize" in Unity anymore.

Comment: this works on 20.04

Answer (score 13):

To minimize, it is not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.

It works on 12.04.  Remember: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.

Comment: For me, control + super + D is minimizing showing the desktop. Again using it, restores the windows.

Comment: Is there too a hotkey to restore the window?

Answer (score 7):

**For Ubuntu 11.10 and earlier:**

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>F10</kbd>  : Maximize the current window. If the window is already maximized, unmaximize it(normal).

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>F9</kbd> : Minimize the current window.

Comment: This seems to stop working anymore.

Comment: bagustrix's answer is the right one below.

Answer (score 4):

If the defaults don't suit you, you can set new shortcuts by opening the Dash and searching for the app "Keyboard Shortcuts."

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu 12 Unity:

Maximize: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

Restore: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>

Minimize: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>

Bottom-Left Corner: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

Bottom: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>

Bottom-Right Corner: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

Maximize or Center: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>

Top-Left Corner: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>

Top: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>

Top-Right Corner: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu you can find your shortcuts in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts. As well, you can show some shortcuts by holding the Super (Start) key.

In Ubuntu 15.10, it works with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> (on the numberpad).

However, I prefer to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>arrow down key</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough, 
in my Ubuntu 14.04 using KDE it's <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `Middle Mouse Button`.

Found in: `Start`->`Computer`->`System settings`->`Window actions`->`Window behaviour`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the minimize shortcut by changing the shortcut to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and now it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: How did you change the shortcut? Could you add that to your answer please?