# Any new keyboard shortcuts in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, keyboard

I have just installed the new version of ubuntu 11.10, called "Oneiric Ocelot", but i dont see any new shortcuts to help improvement between desktops and applications.

I have try Alt+Tab, Control+Alt+Arrows, super + space

Is there any new and useful shortcuts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

Comment: Have a look at this link - there are 11.10 references to new shortcuts.

Answer (score 6):

There are three new shortcuts:

> - <kbd>Tab</kbd> - 11.10+ only - Move to the next lens (When the dash is open)
> - <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> - 11.10+ only - Move to the previous lens (when the dash is open)
> - <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> - 11.10+ only - Switch between an application's windows. Hitting this combo when you're already focused on an application will automatically switch only between the windows for that application. The <kbd>`</kbd> key on US layouts, but Unity will use whichever key is above your Tab key. ([More info](http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/jv5vy/ubuntu_1110_so_far_screenshot_tour_by_jono_bacon/c2fk1bs)) ([Video](http://www.youtube.com/user/whiprush69#p/a/u/2/XHFNnygpvcM))

They are all listed here:

- [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

Answer (score 4):

- If you press arrow down while using alt+tab, then you get a preview.
- Super+m is new. It opens the music lense.

Comment: Oh that is excellent !

Comment: Please add that down arrow one to the master list (it's linked on my answer) - good catch!

Comment: I don't know how to add those button-things. :)