# What is the "show desktop" keyboard shortcut?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I just upgraded to 11.10 from 11.04. Previously the shortcut to show the desktop was <kbd>Super</kbd> +<kbd>D</kbd> (same as in Windows), But now it is not working. What is the new shortcut?

Comment: In my 18.04, the default shortcut for this action is Ctrl+F12.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

**For 11.10 and 12.10**

<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> shows the desktop for me

**For 12.04 and up**

<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> works for me

- [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

Comment: after it shows my desktop,I just take my cursor to the far left of the screen and the launcher appears.. however, I needed to know if there is a way we can change this shortcut back to 'Super' + d ??

Comment: @Swapnil Narendra: Yes. You can do it by reassigning the shortcut. in keyboard utility on the shortcut tab select navigation then you can see a shortcut named 'Hide all normal windows' change it's shortcut to Super +d

Comment: @shymik: It hides the launcher too..

Comment: I couldn't get it to work in 13.10. Shortcut seems assigned in shortcuts area but doesn't work (i.e. does nothing when pressed). The original shortcut keeps working though.

Comment: Note to users with WINDOWS button -- Control-Super-D = Control-WINDOWS-D for us.

Comment: Control-Alt-D and Windows-D work for me

Comment: And nowadays? Ubuntu 19.10? Neither SUPER+D or CTRL+ALT+D work for me.

Answer (score 22):

In Settings, select keyboard then go to shortcut tab -> navigation -> Hide all normal windows -> click on predefined shortcut and press your preferred combination of keys such as <kbd>Super</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but only after a restart.

Comment: @Woeitg This green accent looks wonderful! Care to share how to achieve the look?

Comment: it was a long time ago. I dont remember