# Is there a way to set icons on the dock bar just like Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, icons, workspaces, ubuntu-dock

I'm trying to make my Gnome desktop look like my old Unity desktop as much as possible, and I have noticed that I can't put some icons on the dock bar.

I've done some research and found some code implementation into some system files (I think); so I couldn't venture for it.

What I'm really missing is (My dock bar is at bottom currently):

1. Show desktop button
2. Show trash icon in the right corner (I've moved Apps icon to the left corner)
3. Switch between workspaces button (4 workspaces at 1 screen button)

These buttons are what I liked in Unity the most. Are these changes possible in Gnome 3 or is it impossible because of different desktops?

I'm using version 18.04, what would your suggestions be?

Comment: See this for a "show desktop" icon: https://askubuntu.com/questions/903532/can-i-add-show-desktop-to-the-gnome-dash Other, afaik, are currently *almost* not possible right now.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you just use Unity instead of trying to fit a square peg into a round hole? I haven't finished my project to create a test environment to upgrade my programs and convert my data to **18.04** yet, but I read there have been improvements in this cycle that make Unity better than Gnome for laptop users with external monitors. There might be other improvements in Unity that you would benefit from.

Comment: A not-so-elegant workaround for trash icon: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067164/remove-trash-icon-from-desktop-and-add-to-ubuntu-dock-in-ubuntu-18-04