# show desktop icon to the launcher 18

Tags: 18.04, launcher, ubuntu-dock

I want to enable "show desktop icon to the launcher" as in ubuntu 16.04. I cannot find the why. Is this option somewere in ubuntu 18?

Comment: Things have changed, Ubuntu 18.04 has GNOME instead of Unity as in Ubuntu 16.04 and Unity Launcher and Ubuntu Dock are two different things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I add "Show desktop" to the GNOME dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903532/can-i-add-show-desktop-to-the-gnome-dash) Also you can [switch back to Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040890/how-to-make-ubuntu-18-04-desktop-to-be-like-ubuntu-14-04-use-unity).