# Minimizing all windows by clicking on a random part of the desktop

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.10, desktop-icons, show-desktop, click-policy

I'd like to know if there is a way to minimize all windows by clicking on a random part of the desktop (if the desktop is not completely hidden by the windows).

Comment: Don't think that's *easily* doable, but there are alternatives, e.g. [having a "show desktop" icon in the dock](https://askubuntu.com/q/903532/480481); also there are keyboard shortcuts, GNOME extensions which put a "show desktop" button in the top bar (please read the linked *question* too, not just the answer(s)).

Comment: Hi @pomsky i hope that this feature will be implemented in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late,

but I found a [gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/760/minimize-all/) that add a little button in the top bar to do that

#### edit

[how to install a gnome extension](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/)

Comment: More details are needed to make this an answer. Where to find the app? How to install the app? Where in the app is this setting? That info would make this an answer.

Comment: Hello @orkeilius, please add the informations required by David; they are fundamental in order to understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The goal can be reached by installing the gnome extension [Minimize All](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/760/minimize-all/); it can be installed by following these steps.

1. Log into the Linux device
2. Execute the following commands in a terminal in order to install gnome tweaks:

   ```
        # install gnome tweaks utility
        sudo apt update
        sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
        # create the extensions directory
        mkdir /.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions -p
        # output the gnome shell version
        gnome-shell --version
   ```
3. Open a web browser and navigate to https://extensions.gnome.org/
4. Search for an extension to install and select it
5. From the Shell version... dropdown select the closest version to the installed gnome shell version output earlier
6. Select the latest version available from the Extension version... dropdown
7. Save the extension .zip file
8. Open a file manager and navigate to ~/Downloads
9. Extract the downloaded extension .zip file
10. Browse the extracted folder contents and edit metadata.json in a text editor
11. Copy the value of UUID key
12. Close the text editor
13. Navigate back one directory
14. Cut the entire extracted extension directory to ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
15. Restart Gnome Shell by logging out and logging back in
16. Launch Gnome Tweaks
17. Select Extensions from the left navigation menu
18. The newly installed extension should be listed
19. Enable the extension and enjoy