# DELL XPS 13 9315 Blank screen when waking from suspend

Tags: suspend, dell, power-management, lock-screen, xps

There is some issue with suspend and resume with ubuntu 22.04 and dell xps 9315. I upgraded from the 20.04 factory image to the latest version of ubuntu. Everything works, However I notice that if I suspend the laptop by closing the lid when it wakes up ( opening the lid again ) I get a blank screen. The way I have been 'waking' it up is by quickly closing and reopening the lid. That seems to jar it awake. I checked the logs and I don't see any error so I am not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: See also ["failed to enable link training" when resuming from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/a/1470563/327339)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop and also noticed this issue after updating to 22.04. I was able to "solve" this issue by using xorg instead of wayland as the windowing system.

Comment: Works for me on a brand new Dell Precision 5570 with a brand new Ubuntu 22.04 install!

Answer (score 1):

It can be helped by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> too, without switching back to Xorg.

Still a bug, though. Hope it gets fixed.

Comment: Works for me on a brand new Dell Precision 5570 with a brand new Ubuntu 22.04 install, when running the Wayland (default) window manager!

Answer (score 0):

3 Fixes:

1. As you said in your question, close the lid and open it back up again.
2. Press Ctrl + Alt + F1 to un-blank the screen.
3. Use the X11 window manager instead of Wayland. To change this, see my instructions [in my longer answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1470563/327339).

For full details and more info, see my longer answer: ["failed to enable link training" when resuming from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/a/1470563/327339)