# Why do numbers appear over open and/or pinned apps when i hold down Super?

Tags: unity, launcher

When i hold down the super (windows) key, numbers and in some cases letters appear over open apps and other unity things (workspace switcher, trash).

The first 10 Open or pinned apps are numbered 1, 2, 3..  ..8, 9, 0. Subsequent apps are not numbered.

What are the numbers/letters for?

Comment: See the first answer in this previous question http://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>the number/letter</kbd> it will focus/open that program the same way your mouse would.

All the key board shortcuts available for unity are listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts).

Here is a quick list:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

while holding the SUPER key, you can press the numbers/letters that appeared and the get the same effect as a mouse click on that symbol would have.

To learn more about the keyboard shortcuts of unity look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts).