# Expo and Workspace shortcut Super + S not working

Tags: 11.10, unity, shortcut-keys, window-manager, workspaces

It says [here](http://www.webscopia.com/2011/10/unity-basics-and-keyboard-shortcuts-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/#Screenshots-9) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts) that the keyboard shortcut for expo mode of all windows, while zooming out on workspaces, is `Super+S`.

However, when I push the command it just zooms out the workspaces; it does not do the expo mode. How can I fix this?

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity.

Comment: what do you mean by "zooming out the workspaces"? Cause actually thats what expo does...it zooms out and shows you all four workspaces.

Comment: It's worth noting that Unity in 10.10 actually had this behavior, where Scale and Expo (if you can call them that) were activated at the same time when using the workspace switcher. This was probably due to the fact that it was based on Mutter back then, as GNOME Shell exhibited similar behavior in its own Activities view. Now that Unity has switched to Compiz in 11.04 and later, I don't know if this is possible anymore, at least not by default.

Answer (score 3):

What you're thinking of is probably <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

From http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Expo :

"The Expo plugin allows you to zoom out and see all viewports at once, as well as re-arrange windows between them. It is also useful for visually identifying a viewport before switching to it, as all windows are shown as scaled, live previews."

Is this what is happening?

Do you instead want thumbnails of windows to appear, so that you can switch between them? Try "Scale" ( http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Scale ).