# Is there a shorcut to access the last files used?

Tags: 11.10, unity, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

Is there any shortcut to access the latest files used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using unity, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will open a list recently used files.

For more unity shortcuts, please have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts/28087#28087).