# How do I disable the orange resizing of windows when I put them up against the edge of the screen?

Tags: unity, compiz

Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity.
How do I disable the orange resizing of windows when I put then up against the edge of the screen. -And instead move then to another workspace next that edge?
I have tried everything a could find in ccsm. -many things don't work any more, are unity disabling them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The orange window is created by the "*Grid*" plugin. Deactivate it in CCSM if you don't want it.

To change the workspace activate the "*Edge Flip*" options in the "*Edge Flipping*" tab of the "*Desktop Wall*" plugin and activate the binding you want in the "*Bindings*" tab.

Comment: If you get a reported conflict between 'edge flip left' & 'reveal edge left' I believe you can ignore that & have both. There is a difference between the cursor on left edge & a cursor grab hitting the left edge. (had a bug on that but has gone nowhere). Also in the default 2X2 you may find going up off of the top edge an issue, if so then just use the bottom edge to go to Ws above or grab the window in it's body area (Alt+left click)

Comment: Florian, Thanks! you made my life better. would never had figured that out. tried everything.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think you could do that, you're trying to emulate old
school window management. Anyhow, if you change the unity
defaults, then you really can't file bugs against it, and
we can't make it better.

To move *any* window around to another desktop use:

```
CTRL+ALT+SHIFT <ARROW-DIRECTION>
```

It's actually faster than mouse dragging your window to
a new desktop and you keep it's relative position.

Comment: Thanks. -I am my self old school. 43 years with a big red beard, and wearing sandals all year. -living far north. I love Unity, but it lacks options.

Comment: I hear that, I'm a sloppy focus junky myself but it just doesn't jive the current unity design. I found that once I motivated myself to use the keyboard shortcuts that it was easier to shed my old ways.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts/