# Where is "Super" key for Ubuntu running on Mac OS X with Vmware Fusion

Tags: keyboard, vmware, mac

Host OS: Mac OS X Lion
Guest OS: Ubuntu 11.10
Virtualization: Vmware Fusion

I am the type of person that relies heavily on shortcuts. The fact that I don't have "Super" key on my Mac keyboard really bothers me. At first, I thought the apple/command key would be mapped to the "Super" key in Ubuntu by default, but it didn't work like that. How can I make "Super" key available to my setup? Thanks.

Below are shortcuts that involved the "Super" key. I have labelled the ones that didn't work for me.

**Launcher**

- Hold `Super` - Invoke the Launcher.
- Hold `Super`, then `1` or `2` or `3` and so on until `0` - Open or
  focus an application. The number corresponds to the location of the
  icon on the launcher from top to bottom.

  - Adding `Shift` will open a new instance of the application if it's
    already open.
  - Holding the key is also useful when you want to get to
    the Launcher but do not want to invoke the Dash.
- `Super`-`T` - Open the rubbish bin/trash can.

**Dash**

- Tap `Super` - Opens the Dash. The open signal is sent when you let go
  of the key, not when you push it down, so if it feels slow just let
  go of the key earlier.
- **(not working)**`Tab` - 11.10+ only - Move to the next lens (When the dash is open)
- **(not working)**`Shift`-`Tab` - 11.10+ only - Move to the previous lens (when the dash is
  open)
- **(not working)**`Super` - `A` Open Applications lens
- **(not working)**`Super` - `F` - Open Files & Folders lens
- **(not working)**`Super` - `M` (11.10+ only) - Open the music lens

**Window Management**

- **(not working)**`Super` - `W` - Spread mode, zoom out on all windows in all
  workspaces.
- **(not working)**`Super` - `D` - Minimize all windows; hitting it again restores them.

**Workspace Management**

- **(not working)**`Super` - `S` - Expo mode (for everything), zooms out on all the
  workspaces and lets you manage windows.

Comment: On VirtualBox right command key works as the Super key.

Answer (score 1):

If you Ubuntu will interpret the Windows/Start Menu key as the Super key then you can map it from the `Keyboard & Mouse` dialog in Fusion. From the VMware Fusion menu, select `Preferences` then go to the `Keyboard & Mouse` tab. From there you can add and delete keyboard mappings.

If the problem is that Ubuntu isn't interpreting the Windows key correctly, you should use the `xmodmap` command in a X startup file. For a complete tutorial try [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MappingWindowsKey)

Comment: thx for your response. I've checked the `Keyboard & Mouse` settings, and the Mac Command key is already mapped to the Windows key. It looks like my Ubuntu is not interpreting the Windows key as the Super key. Do you know how I can correct that? Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer to include help on changing Ubuntu.

Comment: I followed the instructions but that didn't make a difference in my case. I have tried all the shortcuts involving the "Super" key listed on [this page](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts). For some the Windows key behaves as the "Super" key while for the others it acts as a "Ctrl" key. I have updated my original post to reflect which shortcuts work and which ones don't.

Comment: I used **logkeys** to capture the key stroke from the Windows key. The result shows that the Windows key was interpreted as **Meta** key. Could this be the cause of the problem that I am experiencing? If so, any idea how could it be corrected? (I am so confused between the many different modifier keys out there)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, all I had to do is disable the key mappings from fusion (i use the touchpad to swipe at osx level - no need for super-tab)