# How do I quickly switch between workspaces in unity?

Tags: unity, workspaces, shortcut-keys

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity and would like to switch between workspaces with a keyboard shortcut.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

Answer (score 172, accepted):

The shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> + `arrow keys` allows you to move in the workspaces.

You'll need to [turn workspaces on](https://askubuntu.com/a/283758/) if you're on 13.04+.

Comment: Under VMware (where Ctrl+Alt are the host OS escape keys) I'm unable to use left+right, but up+down work fine. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: @jocull: Press <kbd>HostKey</kbd> (and release. No key combination.) Then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+↓/↑ as instructed. A good host key (=that has few collisions with typical Windows software) imho is right Ctrl.  - If you stick with yours: try Ctrl-Alt (and release), then followed by the above.

Comment: As of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Super+S works, but not Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right

Comment: @Fabián any idea why? I have 17.10 since weeks and it worked all well until today. For some reason it stopped working rght now. Any workaround to have this back? Workspace and this keyboard navigation is the only reason I keep Unity

Comment: Answering to myself : as of 16.04, follow this answer (read the comment too) https://askubuntu.com/a/301595/787021

Comment: Specifically the Up and Down arrow keys! For some reason I was thinking left and right and it wasn't working.

Comment: Works great on Debian 9 as well. Thanks

Answer (score 77):

In 13.04 workspaces are disabled by default. To enable them, open "Appearance" from the dash. It looks like this:

[image]

Switch to the "Behavior" tab and check "Enable workspaces".

[image]

After that the normal shortcuts will work:

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for the workspace overview and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Keys</kbd> to switch between the individual workspaces.

Comment: +1 I was searching for that workspace overview shortcut

Answer (score 40):

In 12.04 and above, you can set shortcuts for this by launching *keyboard* from the Dash and choosing the shortcuts tab.  Choose the *Navigation* option, then just change the various settings for *Switch to workspace...*

[image: The Keyboard control panel, including the Shortcuts options]

I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> for workspace 1, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> for workspace 2 and so on.

This setting can also be changed in CompizConfig Settings Manager (not installed by default, so `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` if you want to use it).  That program will also let you set things like moving to the next workspace when your mouse hits the edge of the screen - a setting I find too fiddly to use personally, but some might like.

Comment: With many workspaces, here is what I needed to go to. 

To get through time and time again with speed.

Comment: `CTRL-ALT-F1` led me to a CLI and I didn't know how to get back to GUI from there, so I had to reboot. Advice to future readers: IF YOU DON'T KNOW HOW TO GET FROM TTY1 TO UNITY, DON'T HIT `CTRL-ALT-F1` :D

Comment: Just for the record, if you hit CTRL+ALT+F1 and get to tty1 you can go back to your desktop with CTRL+ALT+F7. I think it is this way in any linux distro

Comment: Oddly enough, I thought this was true, but I recently installed Kubuntu 18.04 and it sets up its graphical environment on tty1, so hitting CTRL-ALT-F1 does nothing and you have to use tty2 through 6 instead! No idea why they changed what I considered to be something of a standard.