# Ubuntu 14.10/15.04 keyboard shortcuts problem

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I've noticed some time ago that some of my shortcuts in Ubuntu 14.10. stopped working. I hoped that update to 15.04. will fix it but unfortunately, that was not the case. I have a problem only with few shortcuts, not all of them.
For instance:

- default shortcuts to move windows to left or right (C<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>left/right</kbd>). I've tried to do this with mouse by dragging window but it stoped working as well...
- default shortcuts for managing workspaces (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd>).

I've been googling this already but I didn't find any solution. It seems to be unity problem but I don't have any other ideas to fix it.

Comment: Does changing them and using the new one work?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help :)
Sadly, changing them and using new didn't worK :<

Comment: Can't talk now (late, UK) but will help tomorrow... I have a theory. In case anyone else comes along, **ccsm** may mean something to you?

Comment: Im having the same problems on all 3 of my 15.04 machines - even one of them being a fresh install - interestingly enough - it seems that if I restart the machine, they work again - but on next boot, they stop working. Quite strange! 
ccsm is great and all, but it would be a real pain to have to re do all of the default shortcuts -

Comment: i've been trying to find solution ccsm but with no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this after few months!

Found answer here.
[workspace switching via ctrl + alt + arrow not working after upgrade to 13.04, how to fix this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300974/workspace-switching-via-ctrl-alt-arrow-not-working-after-upgrade-to-13-04-h)

Hope it helps.

Comment: **Attention LQ queue reviewers:** OP answering own question! VTC original Q please and leave A intact!