# Did Unity disable keyboard shortcuts changes?

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys

This is a new computer and a new install of 11.10. I've launched 'keyboard' from Dash and try to change a keystroke, but no cigar. Nothing happens.

This has happened ever since I installed 11.10 on my other computers as well (but those computers were upgrades from 10.10 with custom keystrokes).

Is there another way to change keyboard shortcuts that I'm not aware of?

Comment: are you trying to define a shortcut that is already "taken" by compiz? Please can you add to your question what command and shortcut you are attempting.

Comment: Also check these excellent answers, [Unity Keyboard / Mouse Shortcuts](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts).

Comment: @lqlarry, I already checked that excellent Q&A. Thanks.

Comment: @fossfreedom, I was trying to change the 'Terminal' command with the [P] button. The Acer Aspire has an extra programmable button.

Comment: I also tried to 'just' disable the command by pressing [Backspace] to no avail. Keyboard just doesn't respond to any keypress in non of the three computers.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem or are you still looking for help? It seems to sound more like a bug, have you filed it in Launchpad?

Comment: I'm still having the same problem. On my desktop, I had [windows]+t for Terminal, but Dash has this key assigned to 'Trash'. So, I disabled the shortcut for terminal (that worked, strangely) and then [windows]+t started behaving as trash. However, [ctrl]+[alt]+t doesn't work for terminal... Ergo, I'm f*cked. It's not a mayor problem, as [windows], t, [enter] will get me to Terminal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that with 12.04, all previous shortcuts that I set after upgrading were lost. Also, resetting the Unity plugin for Compiz also disrupts this.

But, I would recommend using the Compiz Config Settings Manager. You can install it by running this in Terminal:

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

These shortcuts seem to override those set in the actual Keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu Settings, and those set in MyUnity and UbuntuTweak.

This might not be exactly what you need, but I figured that it would be worth a shot.

Comment: I'll give that a try. What I don't understand is that everybody uses compiz, but it's not standard to the installation.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package compiz-config-settings-manager

Comment: Oops! I accidentally named the package incorrectly. It's supposed to be `compizconfig-settings-manager`. I believe the reason that this application is not standard on Ubuntu installs is due to the instability that it can cause if using too many effects. Compiz is a compositor that is already installed on your machine, I believe, and this is just an application that lets you change particular parameters. Changing just keyboard shortcuts, however, should not effect your system's stability. I'll edit my post to have a correct package title.

Comment: This works like a charm... once you find out how it works :-)