# Is there a keyboard shortcut for the indicator area?

Tags: unity, indicator

There is a bunch of functionality that is available in the Unity system tray (open/show pidgin, show amarok, turn on/off wireless, switch wireless network, etc).

I want to get access to that functionality from the keyboard, but can't figure out how.  Does anyone know if there is a built-in or installable/configurable way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F10, then cursor keys.

The key in configurable in the compiz configuration manager (not installed by default).

- [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

Comment: I had to press Alt + F10 on Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: @ams F10 doesn't work for me ️

Comment: @MasoudBorbor are you even using Unity? It's been largely discontinued a while now...

Comment: @ams no I am not, when Ubuntu used to use Unity, I used Ubuntu Gnome!

Comment: @MasoudBorbor OK, I think I can see why the Unity shortcuts don't work for you!

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>, and then <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd>.

Comment: This probably assumes there is a "File" menu in the currently running program that can be accessed with Alt-F.  However, not all programs have a file menu, and in other languages, the file menu and shortcut keys may be named differently.

Comment: @Flimm doesn't work for me ️

Comment: @MasoudBorbor This question is about Unity. If you are using a recent version of Ubuntu, you are probably not using Unity, but GNOME Shell.