# How do I focus on the status bar with keyboard in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys, focus, statusbar

Connecting to internet is only the time when I really **need** to use my mouse.

I give priority to my keyboard. I only use mouse when I'm tired of using keyboard or in the condition I listed above.

Actually I can't focus on the status bar. What's the keyboard shortcut to focus there?

*(By **status bar**, I mean the panel where time, network status etc. are shown.)*

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: flagged as duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/86477

Comment: @fossfreedom, Not a duplicate, this question relates to Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> *(just F10)* opens up the first dropdown. And then arrow keys can be used to navigate.

<sub>From @ams's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/86478/49715)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Unity, press Alt-F10. That will put the focus on the statusbar.

Now move with arrow keys.

Comment: Pressing Alt-F10 is maximizing my current window.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> moves the focus to the top bar.
Now to select the indicator applet items, use the left arrow key <kbd><</kbd>.

Comment: Is it specific to 12.04?, because it is behaving different with that shortcut.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, and I tested it before posting this. On pressing and holding <kbd>Super</kbd>(Windows Key), you can see this shortcut in the list.

Comment: How is it behaving for you? On pressing Alt + F10 the `File` menu might open up, but still you can press the left arrow key, to get to the items in the indicator applet section.

Comment: I'm using 11.10. When not maximized, pressing that combination maximizes the current application window. Pressing arrow keys with Alt + F10 did not works as well.

Comment: @Santosh, Yes it won;t work, as you had thought, this shortcut is specific to Unity. All answers are telling about this only. I don't know the shortcut in 11.10, will share it if I find one.

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold the Win key to show available shortcuts. You will see that Alt-F10 focuses on the indicator applets, and using cursor keys you can navigate them.

Of course, you can change that shortcut.

Comment: **1.** Pressing Win shows shortcuts but only for launcher bar ([1-10], t, s). **2.** Pressing Alt-F10 maximizes current window instead.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Any particular kind of flavor? The key bindings I (and others) mentioned are for vanilla Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Isn't there any combination for older versions? I'm on 11.10.

Comment: I don't see them. I would, however, recommend upgrading to 12.04 (11.10 is the unstable release, and in overall very similar to 12.04)