# Ubuntu HUD - PPA for precise only?

Tags: 11.10, ppa, repository, add-apt-repository, hud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Unity HUD and how can I install it on my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98132/what-is-the-unity-hud-and-how-can-i-install-it-on-my-system)

I read Marks blog regarding HUD [Hud - Blog](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/939) I went to install the PPA from here [Hud PPA](https://launchpad.net/~unity-team/+archive/hud).

I used the usual command to install a PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unity-team/hud
```

However when I update it cannot find this ppa.

```
Fetched 1,474 kB in 11s (133 kB/s)                                             
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-     team/hud/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity- team/hud/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-team/hud/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Looking in the PPA information it states I can also add it via

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-team/hud/ubuntu precise main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-team/hud/ubuntu precise main
```

Does that mean the PPA won't work with oneiric?
If it should have I done something wrong?