# Why is HUD not installing on 12.04?

Tags: unity, 12.04, hud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Unity HUD and how can I install it on my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98132/what-is-the-unity-hud-and-how-can-i-install-it-on-my-system)

I have recently installed ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin from usb.
I really want to test the new HUD thingy but it is not installing, i`ve added the ppa, update and upgrade and nothing :( when i press Alt key it just shows me the menu on the top panel.

Comment: Hey, Welcome to AskUbuntu! this is a question on an Alpha Version of ubuntu, Please take a look at  [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/q/18641/17722)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tap the alt-key for it to become visible. Pressing and holding alt the way you've done in the past will have the same consequences as it has in the past. That's the goal. It isn't intended to replace, but to supplement.

Comment: oh trust me, tapping holding long or short i`ve tried it all and nothing :)

Comment: This is why I removed HUD after just two days of trying to find some way of testing it without breaking my Alt key. I shall wait until 12.04 development branch is upgraded to 12.04 distribution release at the end of april.