# Is "shut down" missing from Dash a bug or feature?

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, unity-dash

First and foremost; I did a clean install of 12.04, so this is not an upgrade issue :-)

In 11.10 I used to shut down the computer via the dash (superkey and then type shut and enter).
This does not work for me in 12.04.

Is there something I need to activate? 
did someone want that removed from 12.04?
Or is it a bug?

I have googled and searched askubuntu for it but could not find an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is intended by design. This functionality has been moved to the HUD ( [*What is the HUD?*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98132/what-is-the-unity-hud-and-how-can-i-install-it-on-my-system) ) because shutting down and restarting are *commands*, not applications, files, folders, movies, music, or any of the types of data that the Unity Dash is supposed to search.

The Unity Dash answers the question: "Where can I find it?" The Unity HUD answers the question: "How can I do it?"

Answer (score 2):

`Shut Down` and `Restart` removed from the Dash  (they don't have .desktop files anymore). thus you must access the Unity panel's way in order to trigger this actions with benefits in speed.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, sudo shutdown now, enter still works for me.