# What is the "Run Command" dialogue?

Tags: 14.04, unity

1. What is the "Run Command" dialogue that comes up when you press
   <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>?
2. Is it the same thing or in someway related to the menu that comes up
   when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> from inside a application (like Firefox
   for example)?
3. What kinds of commands can you run inside it?
4. How similar is it to the [command line terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)?

I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @Slothworks please be specific, what are you confused about? It looks like you are asking more than one question. Maybe you could narrow it down and ask another question as well.

Comment: The linked question clears up some things. But links to some more specific documentation, some other relevant questions etc, a more elaborate answer to the last question and an answer to the second question would be nice. And I ask these questions together only because I felt they were related. I'd be happy to edit out any part if it is not related.

Comment: And I am also a little confused about the question which has been linked to because although the question title mentions Alt+F2 the body of the question makes no mention of it (although it has the screen which results from Alt+F2); it instead says Ctrl+Alt+F2 which I understand opens a [virtual terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14284/why-is-a-virtual-terminal-virtual-and-what-why-where-is-the-real-terminal). Maybe that question could be edited to make it more clear.

Comment: Some trawling of this site lead me to a answer for my second question; which I discovered is not really related to the other three questions. The answer is [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/115991/312548). The rest of the questions are addressed to an extent in the question which has been linked to above (and has now been edited to ensure clarity). But some more details will be helpful. Some documentation such as the one for a [similar utility](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Krunner#Tips.2C_Tricks_and_FAQs) in KDE would be nice to have if it were available.