# Are there keyboard shortcuts for opening/using the filter on the unity dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, shortcut-keys

Are there any keyboard shortcuts for opening/using the filter on the unity dash? This is in 11.10 in case that makes a difference.

There's nothing listed on the list of shortcuts [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts).

Using the search functionality is not good enough as (for example) not all games show up if you type "games" into the search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no shortcut keys for the filters, otherwise they would be listed in the question you linked.

You can however file a wishlist bug asking for the feature to be considered:

- [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: OK. I've filed a bug about it.