# How do I  show the Applications Lens By Default?

Tags: unity, applications-lens

While I am growing to be more and more fond of Unity, there are a few minor things I'd like to change. One of them in which is the default view of the dash. When I go into the dash, 99% of the time it's after an application.

I'd REALLY like to find a way to have the Applications lens be the default one. Is this possible in any way? I just find it cumbersome to click the dash icon, bottom of the dash select the 2nd icon (applications lens) then select "see more results" to see all of them.

Comment: It also suggests a feature and question that `Could the Order of Lens Menu be edited according to User Requirements`.

Comment: For Lens, you may want to use the "Filter results" panel to disable undesirable content for your routine searches, then you can use the icons at bottom of Lens to see other content available by category.  If they can give us the ability to change order this might not be needed.

Answer (score 11):

#### Use the keyboard shortcut

I don't think there's a way to change the order of the Dash lenses without having to modify the source, but the easiest solution is to just use the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to directly open the Application lens.

> Note: <kbd>Super</kbd> key =  <kbd>Win</kbd> key

#### Customizing the keyboard shortcut

Open the `application.lens` file with:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/unity/lenses/applications/applications.lens
```

and on line 8, look for `Shortcut=a`.

You can change the `a` to any other letter to get a shortcut of <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>(letter)</kbd>.

> [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

Comment: Oh, that's kind of nice. Thanks! I suppose these are not edit-able?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Lenses#A_.lens_file Look at the shortcut parameter (It should be a for applications). /usr/share/unity/lenses/applications/applications.lens is the file you will need to modify in your case. (You will need root permisions)