# How to always open the Dash on the Applications view?

Tags: unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I  show the Applications Lens By Default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117144/how-do-i-show-the-applications-lens-by-default)

I hate that I always have to click on the Applications view button after I open the Dash.
Is there a way to make it open to the Applications view by default?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add an image of what you want?

Comment: I don't use Unity, but I thought there was a hotkey, like `Super+A` to do that.