# How do you invoke the HUD?

Tags: unity, 12.04, hud

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 and would like to try out the new Heads-up Display (HUD) interface.

How do I make it show up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default to invoke the HUD you should tap the <kbd>Alt</kbd> button.

- [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

Answer (score 2):

Press and hold the Windows key to bring up a list of keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: This only works on certain size screens, for instance on a netbook you do not get the list - only the Unity dash with numbers over the launchers.