# Keyboard shortcuts for windows

Tags: unity, 12.04, shortcut-keys, unity-2d, shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are Unity’s keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

What are the keyboard shortcuts to minimize, maximize, and close windows on Ubuntu 12.04 using Unity?

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> to close the window

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>↑</kbd> to maximize window

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>↓</kbd> to unmaximize window

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> to minimize window - Does not work for some reason

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts

Comment: Try `Ctl-Alt-Numpad0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (open window context menu) and then use accelerator key (underlined) for your desired option.

**Update**: Also, in Unity (no unity 2D I think), you can hold Win key and it shows you some help.

Comment: Thanks.  All those worked, except `Ctrl-Alt-0`, which is supposed to minimise, but it does nothing when I try it...

Comment: did you do `ctrl+alt+Numpad0`? Only the numpad 0 works for this shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Install compiz configuration manager. Then go to General Options; Key Bindings and you can set the key bindings to perform the actions you need.

Comment: Compiz manager works for Unity2D?

Comment: yes, but handle with care! may break your glassy unity

Answer (score 0):

Long press <kbd>Super</kbd> key to get on-screen hint.
According to that, no shortcut for minimize window.

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> to maxmize window.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I was able to get ctrl+alt+0 to work by going to keyboard settings and remapping it to the same <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> combination.

Although the help that shows up when you long press the super key says that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> should also minimize and not just restore. It doesn't work for me however.