# How to enable 'Tab'bing in Unity Dash (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, unity-dash

I have done a clean install from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04. When I open the dash with the super key in 11.10, I used to tab between all the lenses. However in 12.04 this seems to have been disabled.

How do I enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl-Tab Move to the next lens (When the dash is open)
Ctrl-Shift-Tab Move to the previous lens (when the dash is open)

See this link for more details. [LINK HERE!!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-short-cuts)

I really encourage you to look at that link, there's several people who have made screen shots or guides for the new shortcuts. There's also a working tool where you can hold the super key a little longer and it pops up a guide. (Not sure if that's implimented yet, I want to check when I get home though.)

Hope this works for you. 
Cheers.

Comment: Yea, it works! And yes if we hold the super key for a few seconds, it does show a guide. Viva ubuntu! :D