# Quick keys in Ubuntu

Tags: shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

I want to know the quick keys available in Ubuntu by default. Is there a list of quick keys for hiding, closing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, etc.

How could i make my own? Thanks

Comment: @SOORAJ please don't edit questions which have been closed. That just adds them to the review queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts).

To find (and change) system-level keyboard shortcuts, one can run the Keyboard Shortcuts applet, e.g. via System>Preferences>Keyboard Shortcuts on the main menu.