# is there a keyboard shortcut to open dash previews?

Tags: shortcut-keys, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

You can open e.g. a preview of a file in the file lens right clicking with your mouse. Is there a keyboard shortcut to use instead of the right click?

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate of "What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcut question".

Comment: That duplicate question does give an answer. Last bullet under the heading **Dash** mentions: *Over an item, you can hit the Secondary key (commonly to the left of the right Ctrl) to see a preview of the item, as you can do with a secondary click over it*.