# Keyboard Shortcut for Dash previous?

Tags: shortcut-keys, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are Unity’s keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

In 12.10, there is a "preview feature", which shows a preview upon right-clicking the result in the dash.

I would like to know if there is an equivalent on the keyboard to bring up this preview for the selected item, because I do not use a mouse very often.

Comment: I would install CCSM (compiz settings manager) and go through the options of the Unity plugin.

Comment: No Dice. Searching for preview in CCSM and dconf-tools give no results relating to the dash.

Comment: There is none, this is still a duplicate from the other post that explains all the keyboard shortcuts and key you can use with Unity.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, because I am asking about whether there is an alternative means to access the previews in the dash.
It is not really a shortcut, because the keyboard is the primary interface method, so it is more whether there is an alternative means to activate the selected item.

Comment: It is a duplicated. I added the method that you can use there 'cause is the right place. Check the [last update](http://askubuntu.com/posts/28087/revisions) to [the answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/28087/62483) there.

Comment: @Lucio no, is not. We are looking at duplicated questions **not answers**.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Braiam There are about 50 shortcuts mentioned in that question. Do you think it would be better to ask (or reopen already closed) 50 different questions to cover them all? (I am fine with the view that we should close questions as duplicate if they are really duplicate, but in this particular case, I would prefer all the shortcuts available in a single compact place instead of me hopping over too many different links).

Comment: @Aditya yeah, I prefer to do it right rather that just be lazy. That other question should be closed as too broad. Imagine you are installing program X, but want to modify it a little bit, do you feel fine that we practically tell you "SIU, just follow the guide" instead of telling you how can you do those modifications or why you shouldn't at very least? Whoever wants to get this specific shortcut has to read too much noise just to get their answer, and maybe they probably miss the answer.

Comment: @Braiam: You may call it being lazy but that is how I would prefer it to be. I would want all the shortcuts concerning a single application/environment in a single place rather than being littered all around and having to search all over the place... It literally makes no sense to me to follow the approach you want to follow.. There have been 3 other members beside me who have cast their votes or voiced their opinions accordingly.